# Detecting absence of current in transformer secondary

Tags: bjt, flyback, zero-crossing, common-base

Beginner here. I'm trying to build a circuit which charges a capacitor to an arbitrary voltage in the shortest possible time. I want the high voltage part of the circuit to be galvanically isolated from the low voltage part. To this end, I'm using a flyback transformer. The "on" time, during which the core is magnetized, is determined by a monostable 555 timer. To have as little "dead time" as possible, I would like to **determine the moment at which all of the energy in the core has transferred into the capacitor**, so I can restart the 555 timer.

Whenever there is current flowing from the transformer into the capacitor, there will be a voltage equal to Vcc + Vcap / N present at the drain terminal of the MOSFET. After the core has demagnetized, the voltage will be just Vcc.

Such a feedback circuit must satisfy a few requirements: First, it should not draw excessive amounts of current from the transformer, since that would decrease the efficiency. Secondly, it must be able to handle a relatively large range of voltages. Assuming a turn ratio of 1:10 and a maximum voltage of 370V on the secondary side, the voltage at the drain terminal is 37V + Vcc. Initially however, when the capacitor is discharged, the voltage is as low as Vf/10 + Vcc, where Vf is the diode forward voltage.

The following circuit seems to work, at least in the simulation. The output of the common-base stage is zero for any input voltages below Vcc. The complementary pair of emitter followers ensures that the voltage at the trigger input of the 555 is always between ground and Vcc.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEEb24.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

While I can verify that this works in the simulation, the functionality seems to be very dependent on the choice of R3. Am I correct in assuming that this circuit, especially the common-base section, is very non-linear and thus quite unpredictable. Is there a method I can use to roughly determine the required value for R3, without relying on trial-and-error?

There are additional problems with the circuit, such as the low input resistance due to the common-base stage and the large base-emitter voltage at Q3.

I can't help but think that there is a simpler way of achieving what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to determine the moment at which all of the energy in the core has transferred into the capacitor, so I can restart the 555 timer.

There are a number of ways to check when the secondary current falls to 0. One method is to have two secondaries on your flyback transformer. A second is to insert a opto-isolator/opto-coupler into the secondary circuit, and use the output of the opto-isolator for feedback in the primary side circuit.

Without knowing how you would judge one method as better than another, I can't really tell you which is best. If your flyback transformer is already a fixed, choice, then using a second secondary is, of course ruled out.

[This application note](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva727/snva727.pdf?ts=1607211382141&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) gives an example of using an optocoupler in an application very similar to yours.

Comment: In reality you'll need a snubber across the primary as significant voltages will be generated as part of the flyback. The 555 has two comparators  - there might be a creative way to employ these.